# If there was an infinite amount of matter at big bang to form an infinite universe how it was possible for a so huge amount of matter to expand?

Tags: astronomy, space-expansion, big-bang, spacetime-dimensions, matter

If there was an infinite amount of matter at big bang to form an infinite universe how it was possible for a so huge amount of matter to expand? Is it better to think that the universe is spatially curved and finite as the amount of matter inside it.  As the CMBR arrives to us from all directions could it be analized and compared to two sheets, one spheric and finite and the other flat and infinite where both of them are hit by a hammer and they react diferently...the first transfer vibrations towards the antipode point where wibrations collect arriving from all directions like in the three-dimentional case of our space and the CMBR. The other, infinite flat sheet transfers the vibrations towards infinity and there is not a point where these vibrations could be seen to arrive from all directions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great distinction between mass and density and what you are referring to as infinite mass is supposed to be singularity of infinite density.
Also matter is not the thing that is expanding,it is the space time fabric itself which is expanding with no common point as centre.

Answer (score -2):

The space that the matter from the Big Bang is expanding into has no matter itself, so there is no friction to slow down the process. Because of this, all matter is expanding outward in every direction at light speed.

Comment: [The Big Bang did not happen at a point](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point).

Comment: I agree, but all of the matter from the Big Bang still expands at light speed due to the lack of friction